# Test a private method with a factory

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am new to Unit testing I am creating the unit tests for a method which calls a private method inside, this private method also calls a function from a  factory

```
private string FingerPrintCreator(string any)
{
  using var calculator = mFingerprintCalculatorFactory.Create();
  return calculator.Compute(any);
}
  public string AnyFunction()
  {
    var fingerprint=FingerPrintCreator("xxxx");

    return fingerprint+"YYY"; 
  }
```

so far I have:

```
  private class TestContext
  {
    public readonly Mock<IFingerprintCalculatorFactory> FingerprintCalculatorFactoryMock = new();
    public TestContext()
    {
      FingerprintCalculatorFactoryMock.Setup(factory => factory.Create());
    }
  }
  [Test]
  public string Test_function()
  {
    string Any = "XXX";
    var testContext = new TestContext();
    testContext.FingerprintCalculatorFactoryMock.Setup(factory => factory.Create()).Returns(It.IsAny<IFingerprintCalculator>());
    var result = await CreateProvider(testContext).AnyFunction;
  }
```

after CreateProvider is instantiated  I get System.NullReferenceException at calculator from  `return calculator.Compute(any);`

How can I test it? Any advice would be very appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your setup to return an actual instance (or another mock) instead of `It.IsAny<IFingerprintCalculator>()` (`It.IsAny<T>` returns a `default(T)` which is `null` in this case - `Console.WriteLine(It.IsAny<IFingerprintCalculator>() is null);` prints `True`):

```
testContext.FingerprintCalculatorFactoryMock
    .Setup(factory => factory.Create())
    .Returns(new ....); // or create another mock and return it
```

Comment: Yep I had to make another mock, but yes I had not realised it was not instantiated

Answer (score 1):

You don't test private methods directly. You test your public methods directly and they will make use of your private methods - so your private methods will be tested indirectly.

Comment: That's precisely what the code is attempting to do.  The test is calling `AnyFunction`, not `FingerPrintCreator`.  (The mentioning of "a private method" in the question is a bit of a red herring... The problem has nothing to do with the access modifiers of the methods.)

Comment: Note to self - read questions before answering.